# Java BufferedWriter isn't working

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

Im having a problem with a BufferedWriter. I am reading in a 50,000 word wordlist, using a stemming algorithm and creating a new wordlist that just contains the word stems. Instead of this new file containing any stems however it litrally just contains:

> -

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    BufferedWriter writer=null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("src/newwordlist.txt")));
        HashSet<String> db = new HashSet<String>();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/wordlist"),"UTF-8"));
        String word;
        int i=0;
        while ((word=reader.readLine())!=null) {
            i++;
            Stemmer s= new Stemmer();
            s.addword(word);
            s.stem();
            String stem =s.toString();
            if(!db.contains(stem)){
                db.add(stem);
                writer.write(stem);
                //System.out.println(stem);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Reduced file from " + i + " words to " + db.size());
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output i get on the console is:

> Reduced file from 58110 words to 28201

So i know its working. Ive also tried changing `writer.write(stem);` to `writer.write("hi");` and I still get the same output in `newwordlist.txt`.
I know its no fault of the Stemmer class, Ive tried outputting the stem string (where I commented the code) and that produced the correct output to console so the fault must be with the writer but I dont understand what.

---

**Edit 1**

I simplified to code to:

```
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        BufferedWriter writer=null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("src/newwordlist.txt")));
            HashSet<String> db = new HashSet<String>();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/wordlist.txt"),"UTF-8"));
            String word;
            int i=0;
            while ((word=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                i++;
                if(!db.contains(word)){
                    db.add(word);
                    writer.write("hi");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Reduced file from " + i + " words to " + db.size());
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now i get console output:

```
Reduced file from 58110 words to 58109
```

But the output file is still blank

Comment: I suggest you simplify the code even further. If you *just* open the writer, write "hi" and the close it (not reading anything else), what happens?

Comment: Try to use writer.flush() before closing.

Comment: Removing the dependence on Stemmer completely, and just outputing what is read in has the same effect

Comment: @AlexanderZaykov `BufferedWriter` has an implicit `flush()` on `close()`

Comment: @clairharrison If removing the Stemmers still prints `-`, then that's what's inside the `wordlist` file.

Comment: Do you remove the file between runs?

Comment: Here is the wordlist https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzi9l5fyxxxujvr/wordlist.txt

Comment: @Qwerky In this scenario, close might not get executed if an exception occurs as it is not in finally..so flush could do impartial entries...close should be in finally though.

Comment: @Sajal Dutta There is a catch block, I suppose printed stack trace would not go unnoticed.

Comment: It finishes running safely so there are no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the code as given in the Question to produce a file that consists of one line, consisting of all of the "stems" concatenated.  (Or in the "hi" version, one line consisting of "hihihi...." repeated a large number of times.)

It is conceivable that whatever you are using to view the file cannot cope with an input file that consists of many thousands of characters ... and no end-of-line.

Change

```
    writer.write(stem);
```

to

```
    writer.write(stem);
    writer.write(EOL);
```

where EOL is the platform specific end-of-line sequence.

---

Assuming you are using Java 7, it would be better to use try-with-resource to make sure that the output stream is always closed / flushed, even if there is an error:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/wordlist"), "UTF-8"));
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
             new File("src/newwordlist.txt")));
        HashSet<String> db = new HashSet<>();
        String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String word;
        int i = 0;
        while ((word = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            Stemmer s = new Stemmer();
            s.addword(word);
            s.stem();
            String stem = s.toString();
            if (db.add(stem)) {
                writer.write(stem);
                writer.write(EOL);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Reduced file from " + i + " words to " + db.size());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(I tidied up a couple of other things too ...)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get `Reduced file from 58110 words to 58109` console output is that you only have one `System.out.println` statement after the loop.

The writer should write words **only** to the output file `src/newwordlist.txt` and **not** to the console. If you want your program to output words to the console add additional `System.out.println(word)` after `writer.write("hi");`

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Is this your *exact* class, did you edit it before pasting in?

wordlist;

> the
>   cat
>   sat
>   on
>   the
>   mat

newwordlist.txt;

> thecatsatonmat

My `Stemmer` just returns the word you gave it.

```
public class Stemmer {

    private String word;

    public void addword(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void stem() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) you need to use BufferedWriter.write() as follows:

```
write(string,offset,length);
```

so try:

```
writer.write(stem,0,stem.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your edited code I get one line with

```
hihihihihihihihihihihihihi ............
```

As expected.

Perhaps you intended to add newline characters line this.

```
           if(!db.contains(word)){
                db.add(word);
                writer.write(word);
                writer.write("\n");
            }
```

Comment: I think this may have been an error with Eclipse. I made sure to refresh the workspace, close and reopen the file to check and it still opened it as blank. However when i opened it in Windows Explorer i get the same output as you

Comment: I added a new line and i get the output i wanted